# CPU Usage of Foreground Service with Handlers

Tags: android, foreground, android-doze

How can I get sure that a foreground service can use CPU when app is closed, when screen is locked and when doze mode is active?

There are handlerthreads in which I plan tasks with postdelayed method within the foreground service. I list my test cases:

1. Partial wakelock in foreground service:
   Handlers never delay.
2. No wakelock, device is connected through adb:
   Handlers never delay.(doze mode, background case, screen lock all tried.)
3. No wakelock, app is on the screen:
   Handlers never delay.
4. No wakelock, app on the background, app not destroyed:
   Handlers may delay.
5. No wakelock, screen on, app destroyed:
   Handlers may delay.
6. No wakelock, screen locked:
   Handlers always delay unknowningly.
7. No wakelock, doze active:
   Handlers always delay unknowningly.

Documentations don't say much about foreground services cpu usage limitations. Are there bugs related to foreground services?

Comment: you need to create a pending intent or unbound service

Comment: foreground services are exempt from doze

Comment: Yes, they are exempt from doze meaning android is very less likely to end the service even if it is in doze mode. However, It seems like threads never get cpu time.

Answer (score 1):

The handler's `postDelayed()` is behaving as expected.
Based on [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) of `postDelayed()`:

> Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be run
>   after the specified amount of time elapses. The runnable will be run
>   on the thread to which this handler is attached. The time-base is
>   uptimeMillis(). **Time spent in deep sleep will add an additional delay
>   to execution**

Comment: Thanks for pointing this. Now, I use Timer and Timertasks inside the foreground service but it still doesnt trigger on time when phone goes into dose mode. How can I get sure my foreground service can use cpu at wish?

Comment: If you wish your service should be able to utilize the CPU during sleep mode, you can acquire [PartialWakeLock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK) which ensures that the CPU is running; the screen and keyboard backlight will be allowed to go off.